# Laravel: How to create a data with a requirement of a foreignkey without using URI parameters in a form?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a 2 tables, Courses and Lessons:

Course:

> id, user_id, title

Lessons:

> id, course_id , title

And I have updated their Eloquent Relationship.

Now my problem is, how to create a lesson without using a parameters in the form? Because i think it's not a good practice and prone to security issues, like editing the html tag.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/lesson/store/3')}}" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">Title:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title"  placeholder="Enter title">
        </div>
     </div>     

</form>
```

From my route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'lesson'] , function(){   
    Route::get('create/{course_id}' , 'LessonController@create');
    Route::post('store/{course_id}' , 'LessonController@store');
});
```

And my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Course;

use App\Lesson;

class LessonController extends Controller
{


    public function create($course_id)
    {
        $course = Course::find($course_id);

        return view('lesson.create' , compact('course'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request, $course_id)
    {
        $lesson = new Lesson;

        $lesson->title = $request->title;
        $lesson->course_id = $course_id;
        $lesson->description = $request->description;
        $lesson->episode = $request->episode;

        if($request->hasFile('video'))
        {
            $file = $request->file('video');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $video = 'course' . $course_id . '_ep' . $request->episode . $extension;
            $destinationPath = public_path() . '/uploads/lessons/';
            $file->move($destinationPath, $video);

            $lesson->video = $video;
        }

        $lesson->save();    
        return redirect('course/show/' . $course_id);

    }
}
```

and also, hidden input is not also advisable.

Comment: how do you know the id of the lesson?

Comment: it's not the id of the lesson, it's the id of the course.

Comment: You can store course_id in session when create function initialized, and destroy session when lesson will successfully created.

Comment: I don't think there's any security issue as long as you check in server side whether the user has the privileges to create/update/whatever action wants to do. And, after all, you're using csrf protection...

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to have a hidden input with the id which will be passed with the form submission to your controller.